# Show that the tangent line of a point on an ellipse centered at origin meet the tangent line of the corresponding point on a circle at the x-axis

Tags: geometry

Let $P(a\cos\theta , b\sin\theta)$, where $\theta$ is not a multiple of $\frac{\pi}{2}$, be a point on the ellipse $C: \frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac {y^2}{b^2} = 1$ where $a \ge  b \gt 0$; and $P'(a\cos\theta, a\sin\theta)$ the corresponding point on the 'auxiliary circle' $C' : x^2 + y ^ 2 = a^2 $ Prove that the tangents at $P$ to $C$ and at $P'$   to $C'$   meet on the x-axis.

Hint: Write down an affine transformation that maps $C$ to $C'$     and $P$ to $P'$   ,
and that maps each point of the x-axis to itself.

My work so far: $C': x^2 + y ^ 2 = a^2 \implies \frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{a^2} = 1$

Let $t_1$ be the affine transformation that maps $C$ to $C'$, then $t_1$ is $\begin{pmatrix}x'\\y'\\ \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&\frac{b}{a}\\ \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\ \end{pmatrix}$
and $\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&\frac{a}{b}\\ \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}a\sin\theta\\b\cos\theta\\ \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}a\sin\theta\\a\cos\theta\\ \end{pmatrix}$is the transformation that maps $P$ to $P'$.

How should I continue from here?

Comment: I think $P'$ should be $(a \cos \theta, a \sin \theta)$, i.e., the $b$ in the formula should be replaced by a second $a$.

Comment: Rico: see how I put a backslash in front of "sin" and "cos" and now they look nice and have proper spacing around them? That works for lots of standard functions like log, ln, exp, tan, cosh, sinh, ...

Comment: Hint: affine transformations preserve tangency and intersections of lines.

Comment: My mistake, $P'$ is $(a\cos\theta, a\sin\theta)$ and thank you for the advise for formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don’t actually need to write down a formula for the suggested affine transformation $\varphi$. It’s enough to know that it exists. Of course, exhibiting an object goes a long way toward proving that it exists.

As long as $\theta\ne\pi/2+n\pi$, the tangent $l'$ to $C'$ at $P'$ intersects the $x$-axis at some point $Q$. Nonsingular affine transformations preserve incidence relations and tangency, and map straight lines onto straight lines. This means that the tangent $l$ to $C$ at $P$ is mapped onto $l'$ by $\varphi$, and moreover it intersects the $x$-axis at the same point $Q$ as does $l'$. (It looks like the problem also excludes the cases $\theta=n\pi$ because the two lines coincide then.)

You can certainly bash out the algebra to prove the assertion, but the hint is rather extraneous then. As Tojrah writes in [his answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3220451/265466), equations for the two tangent lines can be written down directly, and their intersection point computed quite easily.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: eqn of tangent at $P:\frac {x \cos \theta } {a} + \frac {y\sin \theta } b =1$. And at $P':\frac {x \cos \theta } {a} + \frac {y\sin \theta } a =1$

Comment: If you use the hint, the equation of the tangent at $P$ is unnecessary.